# Split string by Quotation Mark And Followed By Space CMD Batch File

Tags: cmd, split, double-quotes

I have a string as:

```
"C:\Users\Desktop\Download 4.txt" "C:\Users\Desktop\Download 2.txt" "C:\Users\Desktop\Download 3.txt"
```

Output I need as follow:

```
"C:\Users\Desktop\Download 4.txt"
"C:\Users\Desktop\Download 2.txt"
"C:\Users\Desktop\Download 3.txt"
```

How should I get that using CMD?

Please help.

Comment: I think you've formatted your question incorrectly. I can't see any difference between your String and desired output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's very easy as the FOR command splits a string using spaces and treats quoted strings as single tokens.

```
@echo off
set mystring="C:\Users\Desktop\Download 4.txt" "C:\Users\Desktop\Download 2.txt" "C:\Users\Desktop\Download 3.txt"
echo Original:
echo %mystring%
echo Split:
for %%i in (%mystring%) do echo %%i
```